# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I want to extract POS in pandas. I do as below

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
df = pd.DataFrame({'pos': ['noun', 'Alice', 'good', 'well', 'city']})
s = df['pos']
tagged_sent = pos_tag(s.str.split())
```

but get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 111, in pos_tag
    return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
  File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 82, in _pos_tag
    tagged_tokens = tagger.tag(tokens)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py", line 152, in tag
    context = self.START + [self.normalize(w) for w in tokens] + self.END
  File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py", line 224, in normalize
    elif word.isdigit() and len(word) == 4:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually pass `Series` object to the `pos_tag()` method directly:

```
s = df['pos']
tagged_sent = pos_tag(s)  # or pos_tag(s.tolist())
print(tagged_sent)
```

Prints:

```
[('noun', 'JJ'), ('Alice', 'NNP'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('well', 'RB'), ('city', 'NN')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `s.str.split()` is a `list` of strings, not a string (expected by `pos_tag`. Because `isdigit` is a method of `str`.

Comment: It isn't actually. It is a pandas `Series` instance. Each *column* in that is a list of strings.

Comment: Alright, it looks like a list. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The OP didn't bother to include a traceback, so it's understandable, and that expression *is* the cause. Just not for the reasons you state.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i tried to insert a traceback but i couldn't.There is so much code

Comment: @Edward: I inserted one for you.